# Delay with countdown timer

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, timedelay

I have seen this question pop up a few times while searching but none seem to solve my problem. My countdown timer runs in a service and works perfectly fine except for the fact it has a delay before reaching onFinish(). It will go 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,(long pause) onFinish(). This problem,however; does not occur when I am using the debugger mode from android studio on my device. When the device is not connected to the debugger, my app experiences a delay in time. Is there any way to remove fix problem while still using the countdown timer? Other solutions I saw involved the use of handlers or runnables, but I prefer to say with the countdown timer. The code below contains the countdown timer inside a service. I appreciate any help given.

### Service code

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent != null) {
        if (startService) {
            startService = false;
            data = intent.getIntExtra("the", 0);
            // int progress = data/1000;
            // CountDownAct.timeProgressBar.setMax(progress);
            //
            // CountDownAct.timeProgressBar.setProgress(1000);
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTime(data, 1000);
            countDownTimer.start();

            // timer = new Timer();
            // IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            // filter.addAction(ALARM_SERVICE);
            // registerReceiver(timer, filter);

        }
    }
}

public class CountDownTime extends CountDownTimer {

    /**
     * @param millisInFuture
     *            The number of millis in the future from the call to
     *            {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and
     *            {@link #onFinish()} is called.
     * @param countDownInterval
     *            The interval along the way to receive
     *            {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
     */
    public CountDownTime(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;

        int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        // this is the format which reads the time data from the user and
        // makes it readable
        hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));

        CountDownAct.timeTextView.setText(hms);
        CountDownAct.timeProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
        Log.i("CountDownService", hms);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        CountDownAct.timeProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        Intent goBack = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), alarmtimefinished.class);

        goBack.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        goBack.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(goBack);
        // CountDownService.startService = true;
        //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it, very odd.. Err, i'm not sure if this is really an 'answer', but a solution would just be just forgetting the onFinish and creating your own onfinish with like (millisUntilFinished/1000 == 1) { // .. do whatever }

Answer (score 0):

try to call the timer with 100 instead of 1000

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTime(data, 100);
```

Comment: I tried that before actually but it didn't work. I'm starting to think the countdown timer isn't the problem here. You see an activity is supposed to launch after the countdown timer is finished and this activity will turn on the screen display. I think I need to use broadcast receiver.